# Let $X = D^3 \cup_f S^2$ where $f: \delta D^3 \cong S^2 \rightarrow S^2$ is a degree d attaching map. Compute $H_i(X)$

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology

Let $X = D^3 \cup_f S^2$ where $f: \delta D^3 \cong S^2 \rightarrow S^2$ is a degree d attaching map. Compute $H_i(X)$

$proof:$ I will use the mayer vietoris sequence.

Let $A = S^2$ and $B=D^3$. Then $A \cap B \cong S^2$ and our sequence will look like:

$0 \rightarrow H_2(S^2) \rightarrow^a H_2(D^3) \oplus H_2(S^2) \rightarrow^b H_2(X) \rightarrow^c H_1(S^2) \rightarrow 0$

Making the obvious substitutions we have:

$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow^a \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow^b H_2(X) 
\rightarrow^c 0$

Where $a(1) = d$

Thus $H_2(X) \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{d\mathbb{Z}} \cong \mathbb{Z}_d$

Is this correct?

Comment: It is correct.  This is just the exact sequence of the cofibration $S^2\xrightarrow{d}S^2\rightarrow S^2\cup_de^3$. Also $H_1X=0$.

Answer (score 1):

This looks right to me. BTW, you can regard this as the "suspension" of the "same" sequence one dimension lower, where you have (in polar coordinates)
$$
f: \partial D^2 \to S^1 : (1, \theta) \mapsto 2 \theta,
$$
(for the case $d = 2$, which is the nicest one), which may be easier to understand. The resulting space $X$, in this simpler case, is just $\Bbb RP^2$; the nice thing is that the fundamental group (hence first homology) of $\Bbb RP^2$ is $\Bbb Z/ 2 \Bbb Z$. (More generally, for the degree-$d$ map, you get $\Bbb Z/ d \Bbb Z$, whose abelianization is still $\Bbb Z/ d \Bbb Z$.) [NB: you can compute the fundamental groups in these cases pretty easily via Seifert/van Kampen.]

The only remaining challenge is to figure out how this lower-dimensional-sequence can tell you anything about the one you're looking at. I suspect that the 5-lemma comes into play, with the vertical maps all being induced by suspension, but I haven't actually worked through the details.